# Content Move Weirds on IE10/IE9 scrollorama

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

Im currently developing this site

http://remedia-solutions.com/clientes/0093_Construdeck/Final2/

And im moving the content with top and left. Works great on Chrome, Safari but it moves really weird on IE.

Heres my JS for scrollorama.

```
scrollorama.animate('#entrada',{delay:100,duration: 100, property:"opacity", start:1, end:0 });
scrollorama.animate('#entrada',{delay:100,duration: 100, property:"z-index", start:1, end:0 });
scrollorama.animate('#interiortotal',{duration: 2900, property:"top", start:"0px", end:"-5340px"});
scrollorama.animate('#interiortotal',{duration: 2900, property:"left", start:"0px", end:"5340px"});
```

Edit: I decide to use this JS and it solves the problem but it wont work on touchscroll mouses.

```
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

    function wheel(event) {
        var delta = 0;
        if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
        else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

        handle(delta);
        if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = false;
    }

    function handle(delta) {
        var time = 1000;
        var distance = 250;

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
        }, time, "easeInOutQuart");
    }
```

Comment: I notice the same jittering on all browsers. I don't think you'll get around it.

Comment: Yup but on ie it flickers way too much :/

Comment: That's just because the JavaScript engine in is slower in IE, Unfortunately.

Comment: you should choose a different design strategy for IE, with every step check with ie, so you can either find what's messing up or can tweak with hacks.

Comment: i edited my answer check it out guys.

Comment: You're doing heavy jQuery calls (`stop()`, `animate()` and *reinitializing jQuery objects* as well as *running the selector engine* on **each scroll event**) and @roydukkey has the face to blame it on a slower IE engine?! Write well-performing code in the first place and *then* complain.